# Jenkins Pipeline - I need a global configuration object, bad idea to treat a file in my workspace root as such?

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline

I'm writing a somewhat complex global pipeline library. The library really just orchestrates a complex build, with a whole bunch of steps exposed as vars/* and a single src/com/myorg/pipeline/utils.groovy class that handles all common pieces of functionality. Each Jenkinsfile defines all 'build' specific config, and passes it to a vars/myBuildFlavor.groovy step that then calls all steps required for that flavor of the build. The vars/myBuildFlavor.groovy step also reads on a server config file that contains all config that is global to each Jenkins instance.

This setup works incredibly well. It allows users to either piece together their own builds from the steps I've exposed in the global library, or just set all build properties in their Jenkinsfile and call an existing flavor of a build that I've exposed as a step. What I'm struggling with is how I can access configuration values from both the 'build' and 'server' configuration, plus I have some random properties from steps early on in the build that I want to save and use later in the build. What is incredibly annoying is that I have to pass the entire context of the script around with 'this', or have extremely long method signatures to handle the juggling of all of these values.

What I'm thinking may be a good idea is to write a file in the workspace root that contains all build and server config values, plus any properties that I need later on in the build. Has anyone had to deal with this previously? Any major issues with my approach? Better ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tried this, but you make me want to make sure this works. If you don't beat me to it, I'll give it a shot, so please report back...

The things in vars are created as singletons. So I think you should be able to do something like this:

```
// vars/customConfig.groovy
class customConfig implements Serializable {
    private String url
    private Map allTheThings

    def setUrl(myUrl) {
        url = myUrl
    }
    def getUrl() {
        url
    }

    def setAllTheThings(Map configMap) {
        allTheThings = configMap
    }
    def getAllTheThings() {
        return allTheThings
    }


    def coolMethod(myVar) {
        echo "This method does something cool with the ${myVar} and with ${name}"
    }
}
```

Then access these things like:

```
customConfig.url = 'https://www.google.com'
echo ${customConfig.url}"
customConfig.coolMethod "FOOBAR"
customConfig.allTheThings.configItem1 = "BAZ"
customConfig.allTheThings.configItem2 = 12345
echo "${customConfig.allTheThings.configItem2} is an Int"
```

Since it is a "global var" or a singleton, I think you can use it everywhere and the values are all shared.

Let me know if this does what I think it will do.

Comment: I guess this works, but you still need to pass the customConfig object to all steps defined in vars. If your build was 'flat' and entirely contained in a Jenkinsfile this would work great, but my build is really complex and calls multiple vars steps inside existing vars steps. I guess it's not *that* bad to pass the customConfig object around, but if I'm passing something everywhere, I may as well pass the entire script context around. Basically, this is a really weird paradigm. Am having trouble wrapping my head around good design for it - what I have works, but it's super messy.

Comment: I would not think you have to pass it around. It is a singleton. You can't just access it by name anywhere?

Comment: That's what I thought too from the doc, but if I set customConfig.url in one vars step defaultBuildType(), and then call another vars step doSomeBuildStep() and echo customConfig.url, customConfig.url is null. I have to actually pass customConfig to doSomeBuildStep() to be able to access the value of customConfig.url, e.g. doSomeBuildStep(customConfig).

Comment: Wow. That is surprising. Now I have to build this and play around with it to see if I can understand what is going on. Maybe it only works throughout the main pipeline script, and goes out of scope in the other vars.

Comment: Yeah, this definitely must be what's happening. I also tried setting the values in my jenkinsfile and then getting them from a vars step, but the singleton returns null. I think the customConfig singleton is scoped only to the vars (or Jenkinsfile) file it is set in.

Comment: I think what I may end up doing is refactoring my vars steps to be 'flatter'. My build type vars steps that the Jenkinsfiles call will set the global config and call each build step. Anywhere that I'm calling vars steps within vars steps, I'll write a 'group' step that accepts the global config and calls any steps that actually do anything with full method signatures. It kinda sucks, but it's the cleanest way I can think of to do this (other than constantly reading from and writing to a file in the root of the workspace).